# Concurrent delete and put in aws s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a step function which runs daily, in s3 bucket old objects are deleted and new objects are written.

It works correctly mostly but once in a while, instead of first deleting the old objects, it first writes the new objects and then deletes all the objects in the bucket which is not expected.

```py
try:
    s3sc = get_boto().client("s3")
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    out_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    write_df.to_parquet(
      out_buffer, compression="gzip", engine="pyarrow", index=False
     )
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="main_bucket/sub_folder1/sub_folder2"):
         s3_resource.Object(bucket.name,obj.key).delete()

    s3sc.put_object(
      Bucket=bucket_name,
      Key=prefix,
      Body=out_buffer.getvalue(),
     )
   print("Data Written Successfully.")
except Exception as e:
   print("Error",e)
```

There is no error in the cloudwatch logs. Could someone please guide me in this issue.

Comment: Any timeout/retries visible? (In Lambda)

Comment: Yes, I can see multiple delete markers in the bucket when i list versions @Maurice. In lambda, no retries.

Comment: Right now the lambda is failing silently, the exception is just logged, but the Step Function will still consider it successful - is that intentional?

Comment: No, there are no exceptions in the logs.

Comment: It was an observation of the behavior you'd see if there would be any exceptions :) - What exactly makes you think the delete is happening **after** the put?

Comment: I saw the delete markers in the bucket. new item should be written, but when i list the versions I see that the new object was written and then the deletion happened because of which the bucket was empty.

Comment: Seems like something that could happen if the lambda runs into a timeout while deleting data.

Comment: But, when i run the step function again, it works fine. old objects are deleted and new objects are written. Only sometimes, this happens

Comment: Any S3 lifecycle rules active that might mess up things for you? Otherwise I'm out of ideas.